# django modelform.is_valid() no results, no errors, nothing

Tags: python, django, forms

Been reading for several hours now. Still no clue how this works.
I'm trying to validate a simple user profile form in django, but the function always returns - uhm - nothing(?) ... Even if i try to print out form.is_valid() nothing returns.

Here's the code, maybe someone got any ideas:

**FORMS.PY**

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

def __init__(self, instance):
    super(UserForm, self).__init__()
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput()
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs['value'] = getattr(instance, field)

class UserDataForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['picture', 'academicDiscipline', 'studentNumber', 'location']

def __init__(self, instance):
    super(UserDataForm, self).__init__()
    for field in self.fields:
        if field != 'picture':
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['value'] = getattr(instance, field)
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
curUser = User.objects.get(pk = request.user.id)
curUserProfile = curUser.userprofile
success_msg, error_msg = None, None

if request.method == 'POST':
    user = User.objects.get( username__exact = request.POST['username'] )
    userProfile = None
    user.email = request.POST['email']
    user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    userForm = UserForm(user)
    if userForm.is_valid():
        user = userForm.save()
        user.save()
        success_msg = 'Benutzerdaten wurden erfolgreich aktualisiert.'
        userProfile = user.userprofile
        userProfile.academicDiscipline = request.POST['academicDiscipline']
        userProfile.studentNumber = request.POST['studentNumber']
        userProfile.location = request.POST['location']
        userDataForm = UserDataForm(userProfile)
        if userDataForm.is_valid():
            userDataForm.save()
            userDataForm = userDataForm
            success_msg = 'Benutzerdaten wurden erfolgreich aktualisiert.'
        else:
            error_msg = "userProfileData failure"
    else:
        error_msg = 'userData failure'

    context = {
        'active_page' : 'settings',
        'nav': Nav.nav,
        'success_msg': success_msg,
        'error_msg': error_msg,
        'userForm': UserForm(curUser),
        'userDataForm': UserDataForm(curUserProfile)
    }
    return render(request, 'settings.html', context)
else:
    context = {
        'active_page' : 'settings',
        'nav': Nav.nav,
        'userForm': UserForm(curUser),
        'userDataForm': UserDataForm(curUserProfile)
    }
    return render(request, 'settings.html', context)
```

**SETTINGS.HTML**

```
    <form action="{% url 'twittur:settings' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

    {{ userForm.non_field_errors }}
    {{ userDataForm.non_field_errors }}

    <div class="post" id="profilbild">

        <h4>Profilbild auswählen</h4>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="vertical-align: bottom !important;">
                <img src="/picture/{{ user.picture }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 100px;">
                <img src="/picture/{{ user.picture }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 75px; margin-top: 26px;">
                <img src="/picture/{{ user.picture }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">
                <p class="help-block">Aktuelles Profilbild (100px, 75px, 50px). {{ user.picture }}</p>
            </div>
            <label class="form-label" for="avatarInput">Profilbild aktualisieren</label>
            {{ userDataForm.picture }}
            {{ userDataForm.picture.errors }}
            <!--<input id="avatarInput" name="picture" type="file">-->
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="post" id="account">

        <h4>Accountverwaltung</h4>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="usernameInput">Username</label>
            <!--<input name="userID" type="hidden" value="{{ user.id }}" />-->
            {{ userForm.username }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="usernameInput" name="username" type="text" value="{{ user.username }}" disabled />-->
            <p class="help-block">Der Username kann nicht ver&auml;ndert werden.</p>
            {{ userForm.username.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="emailInput">E-Mail</label>
            {{ userForm.email }}
            {{ userForm.email.errors }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="emailInput" name="email" type="email" value="{{ user.email }}" />-->
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="pw1Input">Passwort</label>
            {{ userForm.password }}
            {{ userForm.password.errors }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="pw1Input" name="password" type="password" value="{{ user.password }}" />-->
        </div>    
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group pull-right">
            <label class="control-label" for="pw2Input">Passwort bestätigen</label>

            {{ userForm.password.errors }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="pw2Input" type="password" value="{{ user.password }}" />-->
        </div>

    </div>  

    <div class="post" id="daten">

        <h4>Pers&ouml;nliche Daten</h4>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="vornameInput">Vorname</label>
            {{ userForm.first_name }}
            {{ userForm.first_name.errors }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="vornameInput" name="vorname" type="text" value="{{ user.first_name }}" />-->
        </div>    
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group pull-right">
            <label class="control-label" for="nachnameInput">Nachname</label>
            {{ userForm.last_name }}
            {{ userForm.last_name.errors }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="nachnameInput" name="nachname" type="text" value="{{ user.last_name }}" />-->
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="studiengangInput">Studiengang</label>
            {{ userDataForm.academicDiscipline }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="studiengangInput" name="studiengang" type="text" value="{{ user.academicDiscipline }}" />-->
            <p class="help-block">Über deinen Studiengang wirst Du bestimmten Gruppen zugeordnet.</p>
            {{ userDataForm.academicDiscipline.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="matrikelNummerInput">Matrikel-Nummer</label>
            {{ userDataForm.studentNumber }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="matrikelNummerInput" name="matrikelnummer" type="number" value="{{ user.studentNumber }}" />-->
            <p class="help-block">Über deine Matrikel-Nummer kannst Du eindeutig als Student der TU Berlin identifiziert werden.</p>
            {{ userDataForm.studentNumber.errors }}
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="wohnortInput">Wohnort</label>
            {{ userDataForm.location }}
            {{ userDataForm.location.errors }}
            <!--<input class="form-control" id="wohnortInput" name="wohnort" type="text" value="{{ user.location }}" />-->
        </div>

    </div>  

    <div class="post" id="seite">

        <h4>Seiteneinstellungen</h4>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="stdSafetylevelSelect">Standard-Sicherheitsstufe</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="stdSafetylevelSelect" name="safety">
                <option>public</option>
                <option>Uni</option>
                <option>Fakultät</option>
                <option selected>Studiengang</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="post" id="delete">

        <h4>Account vollst&auml;ndig l&ouml;schen</h4>

        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group text-center">
            <p class="help-block">&Uuml;ber diesen Button kannst Du deinen Account vollst&auml;ndig von unserer Plattform entfernen. Zur Best&auml;tigung der L&ouml;schung erh&auml;lst Du eine E-Mail an deine uns bekannte E-Mail Adresse.</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center" id="deleteButton">Account löschen</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitSettButton">Speichern</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="resetSettButton">Zur&uuml;cksetzen</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

I have absolutely no clue how to handle it. So i would appreciate every kind o help!

greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never pass the POST data to the form: so it remains unbound, and does not go through validation. You need to do `userDataForm = UserDataForm(request.POST, instance=userProfile)`

What's worse, you have explicitly defined your forms' `__init__` methods so that they don't even accept any argument other than instance - so it's impossible ever to populate then with data. In addition, they actually swallow the `instance` argument and don't pass it up to the superclass, so it is effectively ignored. You should define them like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    super(UserDataForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That works. Also thanks @YPCrumble. Tried this before, but didn't work as well. Now i got one prob left. I can not initiate the userForm. `userDataForm = UserDataForm(instance = curUserProfile)` worked fine, while `userForm = UserForm(instance = curUser)` doesn't show any formfields. While `curUser = User.objects.get(pk = request.user.id)` is `curUserProfile = curUser.userprofile`... maybe it's some kind of type conflict with the form? forms in forms.py are nearly identic now. any ideas?

Comment: ok, forget it. had a ',' at the end of the line, ruining the userForm ... thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate userForm in the view by passing request.POST to it directly - you're passing a user model instance.

Try: `userForm = UserForm(request.POST)`